# How to concatenate multiple rows of subquery results in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter

I want to concatenate all matching data comma separately of subquery with `IN()` function. But this query returns only one data through join and if I am passing static ID like `IN(1,2,3)` then return all data corresponding to ID.

Example:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ", ") AS pname FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id IN (b.product_id)) as product
```

Returns one record:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ", ") AS pname FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3)) as product
```

Returns 3 records:

while `b.product_id` column containing comma separated value.

This is my query:

```
$this->db->select('b.*, st.description as skin_tone, sp.description as skin_profile, sc.description as skin_concerns, pua.product, pua.producttype, pua.category, ua.description as action, t.description as type,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ", ") AS pname FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id IN (b.product_id)) as product', false);

$this->db->from('tbl_basket b');
$this->db->join('tbl_skin_tone st', 'st.id = b.skin_tone_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_skin_profile sp', 'sp.id = b.skin_profile_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_skin_concerns sc', 'sc.id = b.skin_concern_id', 'LEFT');       
$this->db->join('tbl_product_updated_all pua', 'pua.id = b.product_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_user_action ua', 'ua.id = b.action_id', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_type t', 't.id = b.type_id', 'LEFT');  
$this->db->where('b.customer_id', $reminderProductID);  

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

Kindly let me know where am I doing wrong.

Comment: What programming language/framework is this? Please add corresponding tags.

Comment: I am using codeigniter framework of PHP.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking (although GL seems to). If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ", ") AS pname
FROM tbl_product
WHERE product_id IN (b.product_id)) as product
```

Does not do what you expect.  When `product_id` is a string, like `'1,2,3'`, then that is *one* element in the in list, not three.

The correct fix to your problem is to NOT store lists as comma-separate lists.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists; it is called a "table", not a "string".  In addition, storing numbers as strings is a very bad idea.

There is a work-around, while you are figuring out the right data structure.  That is the function`find_in_set()`:

```
WHERE find_in_set(product_id, b.product_id) as product
```

Comment: Thank you so much **Gordon Linoff**  find_in_set() is working fine.